# extract out-links of an html file in c++/g++

Tags: c++, html, url, g++

I want to list all the urls in an html file using g++, and I tried to use grep but I wasn't successful. can anyone help me doing that?

thanks a lot

Comment: How is the `grep` episode related to C++? Anyway, [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454/596781). And a [possibly useful link](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Kerrek you can simply use system() for using grep in c++.

Comment: Maybe [check out this Python script](http://blog.oneortheother.info/scripts/generate-url-list/), too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use boost::regex in order to find url's in html code.

Comment: pretty sure you wont be able to parse urls with regex

Comment: ***The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late-***

Comment: These are some types of urls how can I do that: <a href="url"> or <a href='url'> or <a href=url> or <a href=    "url"> ...

Comment: make your regex for all of these types and find first links from a first type after from the second and so on. Alternatively just use 'or' | for your types.

Comment: @AlexTheodoridis how would you do that? I mean what is the command?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html

Answer (score 0):

Related question about [C++ library for HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser), which you could use to parse your HTML. Then look for `<a>` tags.